# Why does NSUserDefaults fail to save NSMutableDictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I’m trying to save a `NSMutableDictionary` with `NSUserDefaults`. I read many posts on the topic in stackoverflow... I also found one option that worked; however unfortunately it worked only once and then it started to save (null) only.
Does anybody have a hint?

Thanks

Code to save:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dictionary] forKey:@"Key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Code to load:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Key"];
dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Code to add Objects to the `NSMutableDictionary`:

```
[dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:@"Key 1"];
[dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"Key 2"];
[dictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:@"Key 3"];
```

Code to NSLog() values:

```
for (NSString * key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %i", key, [[dictionary objectForKey:key]integerValue]);
}
```

And also the keys are (null):

```
NSLog(@"%@"[dictionary allKeys]);
```

Comment: Really nicely presented question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From Apple's documentation for `NSUserDefaults objectForKey`:
The returned object is **immutable**, even if the value you originally set was mutable.

The line:

```
dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

discards the previously created `NSMutableDictionary` and returns a `NSDictionary`.

Change the loading to:

```
NSData *data = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Key"];
dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Complete example, there is also no need to use `NSKeyedArchiver` in this example:

```
NSDictionary *firstDictionary = @{@"Key 4":@4};
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:firstDictionary forKey:@"Key"];

NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Key"] mutableCopy];

dictionary[@"Key 1"] = @0;
dictionary[@"Key 2"] = @1;
dictionary[@"Key 3"] = @2;

for (NSString * key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

NSLog output:
key: Key 2, value: 1
key: Key 1, value: 0
key: Key 4, value: 4
key: Key 3, value: 2

Comment: Happy New Year Zaph: 
many thanks for your help. I finally succeeded to make it work (through [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:counts toFile:path]; /[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path]). 
Neverthless I have a question on your answer, because I couldn’t make it work with NSUserDefaults. You proposed to change the loading to:

 
    NSData *data = [[NSUserDefault standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Key"];
    dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

I did that but it doesn’t work. Did you really mean this or did you forget to edit my initial input?

Comment: My answer was somewhat generic, rename and fix for your circumstances. The idea is once you can archive to NSData you have something that can be saved/restored by `NSUserDefaults`.