# Saved NSDictionary in NSUserDefaults isn't up to date

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have a simple messaging app, and I'm keeping a dictionary of `BOOL:user` in the NSUserDefaults which simply represents if something "new" has happened in that conversation. `{YES:12343}` for example, means there is a new message with user 123432, otherwise `NO`.

When users interact with each other, I update that dictionary and my view accordingly. And when I leave the app, save the dictionary to the `NSUserDefaults`. When I come back, I simply load it. Everything works smoothly, expect one thing.

When I tap on a conversation to open it, I set that boolean to `NO` (because I assume the user has read the message) and save that modified dictionary into the `NSUserDefaults` again.

Debug shows the dictionary is up to date when saved, but when I tap the "back" button, the view reloads the dictionary from the `NSUserDefaults` and that dictionary is NOT up to date. So my view is showing the conversation as unread, obviously.

Now the tricky parts comes into play. If I do it again, (sometimes once, sometimes twice), the dictionary will eventually show the conversation as read (because the dictionary will finally be up to date).

This tells me some things :

- The dictionary is readable and everything is set "as it should/when it should"
- What I get from the NSUserDefaults isn't updated quick enough/at the right time.

What I fail to understand is : when should I save that dictionary and how? I'm loading it in `viewWillAppear`, and saving it in `didSelect`. Isn't that the right thing to do ?

Some code :

My `didSelect` :
pushDict is an `NSMutableDictionary` object and is never nil at that point

```
if (pushDict != nil){
                [pushDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:_friendship.objectId];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:pushDict forKey:@"pushDict"];

            }
```

And the dictionary loading :

```
if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]dictionaryForKey:@"pushDict"]){
        pushDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]dictionaryForKey:@"pushDict"]];
    }else{  
        pushDictFeel  = [NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all `NSUserDefaults` shouldn't be the place where you save information like this. Try to setup a good data model for this. However your error could occure because you are missing this line:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

From your code I can see that you are trying to save a `NSMutableDictionary`. This will not work since the returned object from the `NSUserDefaults` is immutable. Have a look at this: 
[NSMutableDictionary in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105415/why-does-nsuserdefaults-fail-to-save-nsmutabledictionary)

Comment: I tried synchronizing right after setting the object but that didn't change anything :(.

What do you suggest for saving information like that? I thought NSUserDefaults where exactly made simple primitives values like that.

Comment: `NSUserDefaults` is read as a whole. So for large amounts of data you will be doing a lot of unneccessary IO. Create a data model like ConversationItem which holds a `BOOL` "read". You should always synchronize when setting a new object to your `NSUserDefaults`, so add the line to your code again.

Comment: If this doesn't help you like you stated above please try and provide some of your code so we can dig deeper into your problem.

Comment: `-synchronize` should never be necessary (and help) inside the app, when `NSUserDefaults` are used in a proper way.

Comment: Well I ended up cheating my way around by passing the dictionary and saving it in the next controller's `viewDidLoad`, and it's all working fine. I edited to show some code for the sake of the argument but I genuinly don't understand what's the difference between saving "here" and "there".

Comment: Now that you provided some code I can see why it was not working for you all the time. Have a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call synchronize for [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]

```
if (pushDict != nil){
   [pushDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:_friendship.objectId];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:pushDict forKey:@"pushDict"];
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: As I said to @dehlen, it didn't change anything. And according to the documentation I think `synchronize` is really only when you plan to leave the app ; otherwise its should be available. I tried it, it did not work. But in the other answer I said how i went around the problem