# Set NSURLSessionDownloadTask in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I set the `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` in `NSMutableDictionary`. Then I want to save this dictionary in `NSUserDefaults`.

I know that I can't save custom object in `NSUserDefaults` and, after searching, I've found this answer: [How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults), but I couldn't implement to my code.

Here is part of my code:

```
[self.downloadTasksDictionary setObject:dlTask forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",customId]];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.downloadTasksDictionary forKey:@"DownloadTaskDict"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Is there any way to save this `NSMutableDictionary` in `NSUserDefaults`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSKeyArchiver for this. Take a look at this SO post: [Save custom objects into NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986957/save-custom-objects-into-nsuserdefaults) and [Why does NSUserDefaults fail to save NSMutableDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105415/why-does-nsuserdefaults-fail-to-save-nsmutabledictionary)

But, why not saving request descriptor instead of downloadTask object?

In my project I have a NetworkManager which creates a NetworkTask from a NetworkRequest which is a struct. This struct can be created from a json. It works really well.